# Are there any good resources on WFS support in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, development

Are there any good resources on WFS support in ArcGIS?

The only documents I found so far are these: [How_to_work_with_WFS_using_ArcGIS_Desktop](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_to_work_with_WFS_using_ArcGIS_Desktop/00370000000p000000/) and [Consommer des services/données WFS dans ArcGIS 9.2](http://www.arcorama.fr/2007/08/consommer-des-servicesdonnes-wfs-dans.html) But I want to know how it works!

I'm interested in how ArcGIS can be a client to a WFS Server.

Seems like the Interop connection is downloading all data on the WFS server into a local Cache, is there any way to get it to fetch the features on-demand?

**Update:**
I voted for this idea [Make ArcMap an effective WFS Client](http://bit.ly/grpzDa) to get better support for WFS.

Comment: Also interesting would be publicly accessible WFS servers. Last time I looked, awhile ago, there were very few, even from ESRI.

Comment: How it works as in under the hood (as of 9.3 at least, it used FME and does a batch import of features upon project open/layer add), or as in how to set up & work with a client connection?

Comment: @matt-wilkie Yes, there are a few on ArcGIS.com, http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=wfs&t=content&focus=maps but it would be great if there where more.

Comment: @dan-s How it works under the hood and how it's suppose to work with ArcGIS Engine.

Comment: @Mathias : At the moment, I'm not sure how it would work in ArcGIS Engine. (Maybe this code is helpful? http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ArcGIS/ArcObjects/data_interop_overview.htm) Over the next month or two, though, I'll be developing some continuous integration stuff for a client that will hopefully involve programmatic WFS consumption from ArcGIS Desktop/Engine.... if you're still after information, I'll have a lot more once I've tackled that todo item. :)

Comment: @dan-s Sounds great, I'm doing research now for work the customer is going to do in a couple of month. One problem in ArcObject 10 is that the DataInterop namespace is made internal http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DataInterop/00080000000v000000/

Answer (score 2):

Leveraging OGC Capabilities in ArcGIS Server 9.3. Check out the description at http://training.esri.com/acb2000/showdetl.cfm?DID=6&Product_ID=934

http://search.esri.com/results.cfm?h=10&ho=0&q=WFS

Comment: Great, but I'm intrested in how it works when ArcGIS is a client.